# sending PDF file using AJAX POST to ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, jspdf

I'm having alot of problems with sending a jsPDF created PDF file to a .NET API using AJAX POST. Now I could use base64 but would rather not because it increases the file size alot.
When creating the PDF (jsPDF: doc.output) the result you get is a 'string' like the first picture, this file is correctly created so this is not the problem:

[image]

Next step would be to send the data, for this I'm using a javascript FormData() object:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("json", jsonData); 
data.append("pdf", pdfData); //pdfData = doc.output()
```

There is also some JSON content added because with the PDF file we also want to sent extra data.

Next step is the AJAX method:

`$.ajax({
            url: url,
            headers: header,
            data: data,
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).success(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("succes");
        }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error");
        });`

Now when sending this to the server, I look in the network tab and see that not all data is sent:

[image]

The content length is only 1918 long and in the next images you can see how it is recieved by the server:

the pdf file:
[image]

ths json object:
[image]

The content of the JSON obejct is literally: [object] [object]
While the pdf file is only partially sent, only the first 99 lines make it to the server (see next picture):

[image]

If anybody has any advise on this matter it would be a huge help cause I've been trying to fix this problem for more than a day (and if it really is necessary I will have to go back to base64).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did it using base64 just because we were using to much time with this issue.